# How to inherit a form as an original form in all forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, duplicates, designer

What is the problem with this code, which gives this error in [forms].Designer.cs but does the program run?

**base Form :**

```
public partial class BaseForm : Form
{
    public DataSaveApp DataSaveApp;
    private List<Bell> Bells = new List<Bell>();

    public BaseForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        skin.SkinFile = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\theme.ssk";
        skin.Active = true;
        skin.Enable3rdControl = false;
    }
}
```

**Form1 :**

```
public partial class Frm1 : BaseForm
{
    public Frm1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**Form2 :**

```
public partial class Frm2 : BaseForm
{
    public Frm2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**Error Message in Designer.cs in [Frm1 , Frm2]**

*Duplicate type name within an assembly.*

[image: See Screen Shot]

Comment: @Jǝssǝ Where do you see C here?

Comment: @L_J see the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51116621/revisions)